# gh-pages branch on local

Tags: git, github, github-pages, orphan

I want to end up with two branches with mutually exclusive content.  One for gh-pages, and one for master.

When I use the automatic page generator it automatically creates a new gh-pages branch on remote.  I now want to be able to modify that branch locally as a separate branch without combining it with the content from master.

I am using Git 1.7 (no ability to upgrande) so I don't have access to git checkout --orphan

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
error: unknown option `orphan'
usage: git checkout [options] <branch>
   or: git checkout [options] [<branch>] -- <file>...

    -q, --quiet           be quiet
    -b <new branch>       branch
    -l                    log for new branch
    -t, --track           track
    -2, --ours            stage
    -3, --theirs          stage
    -f, --force           force
    -m, --merge           merge
    --conflict <style>    conflict style (merge or diff3)
    -p, --patch           select hunks interactively
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `--orphan`. `git checkout -b gh-pages` will do it. When you want to push it up, just specify the branch with `git push origin gh-pages`.

When you use `checkout` with `-b`, it will automatically track the remote branch if available.

Comment: This doesn't work.  When I do this, all the material from master is included on the new branch.  I do NOT wan't the material from Master included on the gh-pages branch.  I want a clean branch with no duplicate material.

Comment: @Chris This worked fine for me: `git checkout gh-pages`

Comment: @Remis `git checkout gh-pages` only works if you have an existing gh-pages branch.  If you add `-b` it copies the branch you are on along with all the content.  The intent is to create a blank new branch that doesn't include any of the material on the other branches.

Comment: This does not do what the OP asked.
OP: "I want to end up with two branches with mutually exclusive content"
Answer: "it will automatically track the remote branch"
These are two totally different things.